# No virtual method sendEmailVerification() Exception, on user.sendEmailVerification(), in Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to send verification email for Email password authentication in firebase authentication. but on execution of

```
user.sendEmailVerification()
```

I am getting this exception,

> No virtual method
>   sendEmailVerification()Lcom/google/android/gms/tasks/Task; in class
>   Lcom/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser; or its super classes
>   (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser' appears in
>   /data/data/android.crictrac/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.google.firebase-firebase-common-9.4.0_f580acb5d69fe8e0ef1ed0ef0cca7fca68017a21-classes.dex)

I am using firebase 9.6.1

```
'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.1'
'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.1'
'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.6.1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the error, you will see it reference version 9.4.0. You need to forcefully update your project dependencies to ensure you are using the correct version of 9.6.1. Once you do this, you should be able to execute sendEmailVerification without error.

Comment: actually I have updated all dependency already but, but after posting this question when I tried running again it started working. 
Anyway thanks.